# Execute cURL in Python (GET, with output specified)

Tags: python, curl

I want to use the following cURL command in python:

```
curl --get "http://mydatabase:1337/query?i=testa&p=test2"
--data-urlencode "db=test_db"
--data-urlenconde "z=select * from minecraft where "GNR"=3"
--data-urlenconde "-format='csv' -precision"rfc3339"
> test_file.txt
```

I am not sure how to handle it in python. I tried something as follows but I do not know how to handle the output:

```
import requests

url = http://mydatabase:1337/query?i=testa&p=test2

params = {
'db': 'test_db',
'z': 'select * from minecraft where "GNR"=3',
'-format': 'csv',
'-precision': 'rfc3339'
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Is the above written code correct? No output implemented yet.
Is it possible to define output like C:\Temp\test_file.txt?

Comment: The code looks correct, for handling output you can open a file in some address you want and write the response into it.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working fine until now,

```
import requests

url = 'http://mydatabase:1337/query?i=testa&p=test2'

params = {
'db': 'test_db',
'z': 'select * from minecraft where "GNR"=3',
'-format': 'csv',
'-precision': 'rfc3339'
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
open('C:\Temp\test_file.txt', 'wb').write(response.content)
```